# Bootstrap buttons overflowing well, need to wrap and align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get my links, which are styled with `btn btn-link` to wrap around and line up vertically on the left when the viewport is shrunk down to roughly iPhone 4 size:

```
<div class="well well-sm">

        <a href="" class="btn btn-link">link</a>

</div>
```

[image]

I've researched other answers and I've tried adding `white-space:normal` to the `<a>` tag. But then I get this:

[image]

But that's not really good enough. It needs to wrap and then line up vertically on the left like the original. How do I do this?

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vk7fftku/4/
(My first one!)

Shrink the browser (viewport) down to the width of, say, an iPhone, and you'll see what I mean.

Also, any solution should allow the links to flow from left to right at larger screen widths. This overflow problem only happens for narrow screen widths.

Comment: Have you got other CSS? Can you post a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) reproducing the problem.

Comment: No other CSS, only parent element is `container`. I'll do a jsfiddle now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry wasn't too sure how you wanted it formatted.

I double check your jsFiddle you provided.

Add this to the CSS part of the jsFiddle and the words will wrap as expected.

Added the text-align noticed that the texted stayed centered and you do not want that, so add the additional css text-align: left !important; The !important overrides the bootstrap css defaults.

```
a {
  white-space: normal !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

I also updated my original [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jameswassinger/vmftvz1q/4/)

```css
a {
  white-space: normal !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="well well-sm">

        <a href="" class="btn btn-link">link is really long and won't wrap on small screens</a>
        
        <a href="" class="btn btn-link">link</a>

</div>
```

Comment: You absolute bloody legend. You just made my day! Thank you so much! `text-align: left` seems so obvious now, but I doubt I would have figured it out quickly. I always struggle when bootstrap doesn't  do what I want and I try to override it, it always feels like it's not supposed to be messed with. I don't like using `!important` but I guess you have to in situations like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the container class to container-fluid.

Then inside the well use a list-group with li button with class btn btn-link and list-group-item.

Then the text will wrap as expected.

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jameswassinger/vmftvz1q/1/)

```css
.container-fluid {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="well well-sm">
     <div class="list-group">
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item">Accommodation - Holiday and Business</button>
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item">Advertising Space</button>
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item">Agriculture, Farming, Fishing and Forestry</button>
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item">Aircraft</button>
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item">Appliances - Domestic</button>
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item">Automotive Equipment</button>
</div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That seems to always stack everything vertically no matter what the size of the screen?